# How fine grained of an association can I make between SQL Server log files and CPU?

Tags: sql-server, log-files, cpu-usage

On a multi cpu, multi disk, server, I am looking to associate CPUs with particular log files.

I am wondering if is possible, and how, to dedicate CPU power to specific log file work, in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering every write (insert / update) transaction requires writing to the log, this isn't exactly a good idea... even if you could do it, which you can't.

Let SQL server manage it's threading across CPU's.  It's going to do a much better job than we could.

Comment: It would be very useful to me if I could guarantee that certain databases, and database specific processes, have a guaranteed minimum of resources available, no matter what.

Comment: In that case, set your databases up as new sql instances.  You can have multiple running per machine. Then assign the resources to each instance.  OR, Just split the databases across multiple servers.